# Redisplaying form data with errors

Tags: php, post, curl, error-handling

I use a form to collect data, edit it and then use cURL to re-display the form with error messages. The problem is the input data as originally entered is wiped. out.

I tried to re-display the data using the the POSTFIELDS option with an array containing the post data. But that is not working.

Here's the cURL code.

```
errors:
$data = array (book => $book, begchap => $begchap, begverse => $begverse, endchap => $endchap, endverse => $endverse);
//foreach($data as $x => $x_value) {
//    echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
//    echo "<br>";
//}
// Get cURL resource
$url="http://www.seekinghimdaily.org/php_snippets/read_any_passage_new.snippet.php/?e1=".$e1."&e2=".$e2."&e3=".$e3."&e4=".$e4."&e5=".$e5."&e6=".$e6;
//Step 1 - initialize cURL session 
$cSession = curl_init(); 
//step2 - set cURL options
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_POST,true);
//curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);   
//step3 - Execute cURL session
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
if(curl_errno($cSession))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($cSession);
}
//step4 - Close cURL session
//step5
echo $result;
end:
?>
```

Here's a line of the code I am trying to use to re-display the data keyed plus error messages.

```
<br><span style="margin: 18x 15px 18px 18px;  ">Beginning Verse <input type="text" id="begverse" name="begverse" size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo $_POST['begverse']?>"/></span>'
<?php 
if ($e5=='y')
  {
   echo '<span style="color: red"> Not in book. </span>';
  }
?>
```

Thanks again for your patience and assistance.

Comment: Sorry, it is completely unclear from that code example you posted what you are actually doing...

Comment: I send a form in an initial program and then retrieve that data into a second program which edits the data and sets error codes. I am attempting to use cURL to re-execute the initial module and the form in it. It works great and the error codes, set as parameters, are received and processed. From what I had read, I had hoped to set up an array with the values from the form, in order to have them repopulate the data fields in the form when it is presented after editing. What happens instead is the form data appears blank as if there was never any data entered.

Comment: There still is a lot of information missing in the question. So we cannot really say much here. Sending form data as POSTFIELDS the way you do works, so the question is more likely how to handle those afterwards (on the receiving side), but you do not show any code about that...

Comment: I've added the code  I am using to try to output the form with the error messages and the data values entered to the post above. Thank you for your patience in trying to help me find a solution. Form processing and cURL are new to me as you no doubt have surmised.:)